# Golang execute sql prepare statement

Tags: go

Go's sql package already includes the `Prepare` method but what if the SQL schema I have already includes prepared statements?

How would I call the following in go without using the `Prepare` method?

```
PREPARE select_user (TEXT, VARCHAR) AS
    SELECT id, email, is_admin FROM users
    WHERE email = $1
    AND password = crypt($2, password);
```

Comment: http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html

Comment: This *is* what the Prepare method does (except you don't get to specify the name).

Comment: Your problem is not clear. The `Prepare` method from the `"database/sql"` package does exactly that.

Comment: @elmiomar I am trying to call a prepared method that already exists in the sql. I would prefer to not duplicate sql code.